# Firefox - website takes me to new tab automatically and I cannot stop it

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, tabs

So I have a website where I can select links and click a button to open them all at the same time. When I do that Firefox takes me to one of the newly opened links automatically.

I wanted to stop this behavior, so I looked and looked, and eventually found this option:

**browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground**

Now, when I set this to true, newly opened tabs never automatically take me to them. So if I click an ad on a site that normally opens in a new tab and takes me to it, now it doesn't happen. I also tried this code:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>
```

This code opens 2 links at the same time. I was thinking maybe opening multiple links at the same time somehow overrides Firefox. But no, the links opened and I was not automatically taken to any of the new tabs.

Also must be said that I'm having this problem in Firefox 75 and 74. But when I try it in Firefox 55.0.2, I don't have the problem. In Firefox 55.0.2 the "**browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground**" actually works even on the website where I have the problem (I can't share the site because it's behind login).

This appears to be the code responsible to open multiple links on the website I have an issue with:

```
            $(document).on('click', '.statbtn', function () {
            var me = $(this);
            var isAnyRowSelected = false;
            $('.row-checkbox').each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (t.is(':checked')) {
                    isAnyRowSelected = true;
                    $('select[name="status[' + t.val() + ']"]').val(me.attr('id'));
                }
            });
            if(isAnyRowSelected == false){
                bootbox.alert("No Orders Selected");
            }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.openlink', function () {
            var me = $(this);
            var isAnyRowSelected = false;
            $($('.row-checkbox').get()).each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (t.is(':checked')) {
                    isAnyRowSelected = true;
                    console.log();
                    var win = window.open(t.data('link'), '_blank');
                    if (win) {
                        win.focus();
                    } else {
                        bootbox.alert('Please allow popups for this website');
                    }                        
                }
            });
```

So I tried everything I could think of. Many changes to the about:config, restarting my browser, unticking the "When you open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately" option in Firefox. But nothing works. When I open links from this one site using this specific button, I always get automatically taken to one of the newly opened tabs.

Here is a similar-ish problem - https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/bnu6qq/opening_new_tab_problem/

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it? I mean, a website shouldn't be able or allowed to override Firefoxe's native setting, right?

Comment: seems `win.focus();` is the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, because I don't wanna be an ass, here is the solution.

```
            $(document).on('click', '.statbtn', function () {
            var me = $(this);
            var isAnyRowSelected = false;
            $('.row-checkbox').each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (t.is(':checked')) {
                    isAnyRowSelected = true;
                    $('select[name="status[' + t.val() + ']"]').val(me.attr('id'));
                }
            });
            if(isAnyRowSelected == false){
                bootbox.alert("No Orders Selected");
            }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.openlink', function () {
            var me = $(this);
            var isAnyRowSelected = false;
            $($('.row-checkbox').get().reverse()).each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                if (t.is(':checked')) {
                    isAnyRowSelected = true;
                    console.log();
                    // var win = window.open(t.data('link'), '_blank');
                    setTimeout(() => window.open(t.data('link'), '_blank'),1000);
                    // if (win) {
                    //     win.focus();
                    // } else {
                    //     bootbox.alert('Please allow popups for this website');
                    // }                        
                }
            });
            if(isAnyRowSelected == false){
                bootbox.alert("No Orders Selected");
            }
        });
```

Basically, adding a "setTimeout" fixed it. For some reason Firefox needed the delay to process things correctly, I guess, I think. Before the delay, the actions would happen instantly, and I'll just guess that Firefox couldn't "catch up" to it in order to apply the exemption of not navigating to new tabs. But a timeout delay fixed it.

And for anyone that may run into this with a similar issue, it also required an edit in Firefox in "**about:config**" to set this to **True**.

**browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground**

That's all folks :)